# Can we achieve z-index like functionality without using z-index for html email template?

Tags: css, html-table, html-email, email-templates, html4

While creating a html email template, I got a problem with making a large background text beneath the content using tables.
for example :

```
<table>
<td>bg-text-bottom-layered </td>
<td>top-layer-content. </td>
</table>
```

Is it possible to make a top-layer-content without using z-index?

It really helps me if you answer this question?

Comment: Could you create a runnable snippet and also show a picture of the sort of thing that is required because I’m struggling to understand what a large background text means. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You can try using some background and adding `pointer-events: none;` but it is still unclear what you want to achieve

Comment: For email clients , majority of css3 properties are not applicable in which z-index is one of them and we have to use only css2 and html4 https://stackoverflow.design/email/guidelines/design-best-practices/. But the design is demanding to use z-index, for obvious reason making layers stack to achive respective design.

Comment: @SaiGaneshkc it's not quite true that the majority of css3 properties are not available - for quite a lot of email clients a majority is, see e.g. https://www.caniemail.com/scoreboard/ However, z-index is not supported in some popular ones (e.g. gmail and windows outlook).

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the primary method to accomplish this is by using the z-index. Could you share the reasons why z-index isn't working in your case? Also, don't forget to organize your table data by using table rows (< tr >).

Are you looking to have a background image behind your table? If so, I suggest enclosing your table within a parent div tag. You can then assign a background image through your CSS for that div, and proceed to construct your table on top of this background.

Comment: Quite a few email clients don’t implement z-index, see E.g. https://www.caniemail.com/search/?s=Z-index